# Study the continuity of $f(z)=z^z,\ z\in\mathbb{C}^*$

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried (with sequences) to find in which points the function $f(z)=z^z,\ z\in\mathbb{C}^*$ is continuous on its domain.  My result: $f$ is continuous on a $z$ if and only if $$z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus [\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^-} (n,n+1)].$$ Am I missing some point (except $0$)? Thank you

Comment: We need to know your definition of exponentiation first

Comment: I would say beware with your definitions, if you have $z^z = e^{z\ln(z)}$ on $\mathbb{R}$, you should know that there is an holomorphic extension of $\ln$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}^-$...

Comment: $z^z=e^{z\log z},$ where $\log z=\ln |z|+i Arg (z)$ and $Arg(z)$ is the unique angle of $z$ that belongs in $(-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: So you know already that discontinuity points are on $\mathbb{R}^-$

Comment: I think that with another choice of extension, you could get an extension of $\ln$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus i \mathbb{R}_+$ so you would only have $0$ as discontinuity point? but I may be mistaken

Comment: Yes, it is known that $Arg(z)$ and hence $\log(z)$ has discontinuity on $\mathbb{R}^-$ but with the help of sequences I get more discontinuity points on $f(z)=z^z$

Comment: Yes what I was saying is that on a neighborhood of $\mathbb{R}^*_-$ you can define $\ln(re^{i\theta}) = \ln(r) + i \theta $ but this time with $\theta \in ]-\frac{3\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}[$ but I do not know if this is legit

Comment: If $f:U\to\mathbb C$, with $f(z)=z^z$ is analytic in $U$, then $U$ CANNOT contain a simple closed curve with 0 in its interior.  The region $U$ can be any simply connected open subset of $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @kotsos24919 What sequence did you use because I tried with $e^{I\theta_n}$ with $\theta_n \rightarrow \pi$ and it works fine

Comment: Ι get what you say. However, my purpose in this exercise is not to extend my function continuously, but only to study the previous function in terms of its continuity, as we have defined it

Comment: With what @YiorgosS.Smyrlis said, you can deduce with a local definition of $z^z$ that it is continuous on $\mathbb{C}^*$

Comment: For example, If $z_n=x_n+iy_n$ with $x_n<0$ and $y_n<0$ that $z_n\to -1/2$ then $f(z_n)=e^{z_n(\ln|z_n|+i(-\pi+\arctan(\frac{y_n}{x_n})))}\to e^{-1/2 (\ln(1/2)-i\pi)}\neq f(-1/2)= e^{-1/2 (\ln(1/2)+i\pi)}$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis can you explain me if I am doing something wrong on my previous result? Thanks